# SimpleDateFormat can't parse Date

Tags: java, string, parsing, date

i've got a little problem with parsing a String to date. I searched on stackoverflow an thought that i got my answer but its still not working .. so ..

I trying to parse a  String which looks like this

> Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 CET 1985

what I'm trying ist this..

```
private Date getDateFromString(String sDate)
{
    String dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));  
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = sdf.parse(sDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newDate;

}
```

Sure somebody can help me :-) Thank you in forcast

Comment: This code works for me. Do you use java.util.Date or java.sql.Date as import?

Comment: It didn't for me until I added what adenoyelle said, you must have this locale as default.

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Comment: What is the problem you get?

Comment: I think the problem is that he gets *java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 CET 1985"*. That's what I got until I added the US Locale (I have Swedish locale default).

Comment: For maintenance, you should really avoid parsing dates which contain some 18n-able parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on the interpretation on "Tue" and "Jan" because you did not specify any locale (in this case, it takes the default locale (Locale.getDefault())

Try:

```
new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, new Locale("en_US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried whit Calendar?

```
public Date getDateFromString(String sdate) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Calendar car = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date ndate = null;
    try {
        ndate = sdf.parse(sdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ndate;
}
```